# Refactor json pasring of lists

Tags: json, list, flutter, parsing

I have a JSON field called `thematicBiases` which is of type list. How can this json parsing be refactored?

```
final thematicBiasList = <ThematicBias>[];
if (json['ThematicBiases'] != null) {
  for (final element in json['ThematicBiases']) {
    thematicBiasList.add(ThematicBias.parse(element as String));
  }
}
thematicBiases = thematicBiasList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a shorter way of doing it, you can try this:

```
if (json['ThematicBiases'] != null) {
  thematicBiases = json['ThematicBiases']!
    .map((element) => ThematicBias.parse(element as String))
    .toList();
}
```